# Больше и более

Tags: грамотная-речь

Сейчас прочитал ответ на вопрос о "набирать обороты" и задумался: а действительно, в чем разница между "больше" и "более". То есть, я понимаю, что "больше" *больше* относится к количеству, нежели к степени чего-либо. Но, с другой стороны, предыдущее предложение - пример того, как слово "больше" употреблено в значении степени чего-то.
Хотя я не отрицаю, что употребил в данном случае слово "больше" неправильно. Хотя в разговорной речи, как мне кажется, слово "более" воспринимается как чересчур высокопарное.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во многих случаях области значения и употребления  слов "более и больше" различны : 
А) более прохладный, действовать более осмотрительно - сравнительная степень прилагательных и наречий;
Б) уделять больше внимания, знает больше других, люблю больше всего - количественное сравнение.

В то же время значения этих слов  могут совпадать, например: ждал не больше/не более часа, не видел друзей больше/более года. В этом случае количественная оценка относится к слову с предметным (именным) значением.

В глагольных сочетаниях используется наречная форма "больше" или количественный оборот с этим словом: надо больше бегать, больше ждать не могу, надо есть больше овощей, требовать все больше и больше денег, покупать все больше и больше книг.

Но в устойчивом выражении на основе глагола  "всё более и более набирает обороты"  используется форма "более", так как формально при использовании "больше" нужно было бы сказать: "набирает все больше и больше оборотов". Здесь форма "всё более и более" является наречной частицей со значением большой интенсивности действия.

Однако в разговорном стиле грамматическая точность может не соблюдаться, и тогда говорят: "Процесс всё больше и больше набирает обороты".