# Большой и больший

Tags: грамотная-речь

Больш**и**й (например, дом) - значит больше, чем какой-то другой. То есть мы сравниваем.

Больш**о**й - значит просто больш**о**й, вообще.

Но говоря больш**о**й, мы должны тоже от чего-то отталкиваться чтобы сделать такой вывод.
Больш**о**й потому и больш**о**й, что больше чем обычный.

**Вопрос**: Значит ли что больш**о**й по сути является больш**и**м по сравнению с чем-то условно обычным. То есть говоря больш**и**й, мы сравниваем с чем-то конкретным в данном контексте, а говоря больш**о**й, мы сравниваем с чем-то условно обычным, что может не существовать в данном контексте?

Comment: Я сам задумывался о похожем вопросе: зачем в языке две сравнительных степени: больше и более. Чем они отличаются? На форуме этот вопрос поднимался. Ваш вопрос связан с ним напрямую. 
большой/больше - это стандартная для языка парочка красный/краснее. А вот больший/более это дублирующая его замена в некоторых ситуациях, а в некоторых нет. См https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/39597 итп

Comment: Голосую за закрытие, так как здесь нет вопроса, а вы просто поделились своими мыслями. Это форум вопрос — ответ, а не форум, где люди делятся своими соображения по разным лингвистическим темам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, полагаю, что так и есть. *Б**о**льший* - это контекстное языковое сравнение, а *больш**о**й* - это внеязыковая идея о размерах, обычных и отличающихся от нормы. Последнее, конечно, тоже существует в определенном дискурсе и разнится в зависимости от контекста (*большой арбуз* в действительности явно больше, чем *большой мандарин*, например). Но если первая ситуация (*б**о**льший*) напрямую связана с грамматикой и языком в целом (сравнительная степень требует прямого контекста), то вторая (что такое *больш**о**й*?), мне кажется, скорее относится к вопросам культуры и антропологической лингвистики.