# О правильности употребления слова «больше» в речи

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

**1. Область значений «больше» по словарю**

В своем исходном/главном  значении это **сравнительная степень** к словам «большой» и «много»: *скорость больше, чем у других;  три больше двух;  больше внимания детям.*
Но «больше» на этом не останавливается. В частности, оно делит область значений **со словом «более».** Есть у него и три значения **наречия:**

**(1) с колич. сущ. и именными сочет.**;. обозначает превышение указанного количества. Метр б. аршина. Жду б. часа.

**(2) **в отрицат.** предл.** значение **«далее, впредь; уже».** Б. не плачь! Б. ничего не слушал. Б. здесь не живёт. // значение **«кроме этого, ещё».** Сказать б. нечего. Прощаться б. было не с кем.

**(3) разг. значение** **«главным образом»**. Шли б. горами.

Обратим внимание на то, что здесь **глагольные сочетания**. Также отметим, что значения **усилительной частицы** у слова «больше» нет. Кроме того,  нельзя исключать, что «больше» используется **и в других случаях,** которые не указаны в словаре, но это пока не соответствует норме.

**2. На форуме был вопрос о словах «больше» и «более»  (2014 год)**

В полученном ответе я отметила, что различается употребление «больше» в **глагольных и именных** сочетаниях.
[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/39597/Больше-и-более](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/39597/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5)

**3. Почему возник этот вопрос**

Правильно: «***Эта статья больше недоступна***». Я смотрела на свою запись, но предложение не выглядело правильным и заметно раздражало слух. И тогда написала: ***«Теперь (в настоящее время, сейчас) эта статья недоступна».*** Но правомерность замены наречия надо было объяснить, а как?  И точно ли надо менять? А может, если раз десять это произнести, то будет и ничего, станет привычным.

По словарю это наречие, можно сравнить: ***Больше (уже) здесь не живет.*** Здесь отрицание, но оно относится **к глаголу**, а у нас **именная часть сказуемого**. Если «больше» отнести к прилагательному «недоступный», то кажется, что это сравнение: ***статья больше/в большей мере недоступна, чем доступна.*** Вот это и не нравится, кажется стилистической погрешность. Да и по словарю такая сочетаемость не нормируется.

Однако  в текстах эти выражения  достаточно **частотны**. Вроде бы они выглядят нормально, но не всегда. Так что ответ не нашелся…

**P.S.**  Я предлагаю эту тему **для обсуждения**, если она вам интересна. Комментировать не буду (вроде бы все сказала), но приму ответ, если он покажется мне убедительным. Критиковать меня не надо, ведь все сказанное не более чем мое мнение.

**Вопросы такие**: Это предложение стилистически корректно (ваше мнение)? Как выбор "больше" объяснить по словарю, учитывая значение этого слова?

Обсуждение темы [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474118/Эта-статья-больше-не-доступна-как-пишется-НЕ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474118/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%9D%D0%95)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146449/discussion-on-question-by-sharon-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

По поводу: ‟Кроме того, нельзя исключать, что «больше» используется и в других случаях, которые не указаны в словаре, но это пока не соответствует норме”. Если составитель словаря проанализировал использование некого слова и не внёс какое-то значение в словарь по какой-то причине (вроде рассеянности, всё-таки он лингвист, а лингвисты не славятся высокими стандартами качества при написании каких-либо пособий... да и средними не славятся, если честно), то это не значит, что это значение не соответствует какой-то норме, если это значение фактически присутствует в речи и используется людьми.  Может быть наоборот: какое-то значение может присутствовать в словаре, но не использоваться в речи, тогда такое значение скорее не соответствует норме.

**‟НЕ” В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ: ‟ЭТА СТАТЬЯ БОЛЬШЕ НЕ ДОСТУПНА”**
‟Не” пишется раздельно, потому что тут отрицание с ‟не”, а не утверждение с ‟не”. Это можно показать на таком предложении: ‟Он больше не хороший человек”. ‟Нехороший” можно заменить на ‟плохой”, а тогда предложение будет: ‟Он больше плохой человек”, а такое предложение не имеет смысла, так как такое ‟больше” употребляется только с отрицательными словами, вроде отрицательной частицы ‟не”. Это же касается предложения: ‟Эта статья больше не доступна”.

Ещё раз, нехороший человек = плохой человек, предложение: ‟Он больше плохой человек” – бессмысленное, а поэтому предложение: ‟Он больше нехороший человек” – так же бессмысленное. Это ‟больше” без ‟не” не употребляется (или другого отрицательного слова).

**О ЗНАЧЕНИИ СОЧЕТАНИЯ ‟БОЛЬШЕ НЕ”**

Со словами в будущей форме это ‟больше” схоже со словом ‟впредь” (но не совсем, но об этом позже). Взгляните на примеры:

> Я больше не допущу эту ошибку. (Заменяется на ‟впредь”.)
> Я больше не позволю тебе так обращаться со мной. (Заменяется на ‟впредь”.)

Со словами в настоящей форме это ‟больше” схоже по смыслу с ‟сейчас”, но есть отличия, помимо того, что это ‟больше” используется только с отрицательными словами. Это ‟больше” используется тогда, когда что-то было верным ранее, а сейчас уже не является верным, тогда как ‟сейчас” может использоваться и тогда, когда это что-то не являлось верным вообще. Взгляните на примеры:

> В данный момент патчи для игры не выходят. (Не обязательно, что они вообще когда-то выходили.)
> Патчи для игры больше не выходят. (Они выходили раньше.)

Это же касается и разницы этого ‟больше” со словом ‟впредь” при отношении к слову в будущей форме.

Со словом в настоящей форме ‟больше не” = ‟перестал быть” (или ‟перестал делать”, если относится к глаголу).

> Я больше не хочу играть в эту игру = Я перестал хотеть играть в эту игру.
> Он больше не хороший человек = Он перестал быть хорошим человеком.
> Я больше не бегаю по утрам = Я перестал бегать по утрам.
> После этих поступков он больше не герой = После этих поступков он перестал быть героем.

Comment: Мне кажется, что проблема еще в том, что в русском языке указание на "время", которое в английском определяется вспомогательным глаголом, может просто отсутствовать. То есть в данном предложении нет глагола констатирующего временной период, из-за этого не ясно к чему относится "больше" , в то время как "больше" употребляется вместо глагола и вместо "no longer" одновременно. То есть синтаксически скорее всего "больше не доступна" - является сказуемым, то есть сказуемое составное из слова больше и не доступна, которые, причем больше связано с "отсутствующим" временным глаголом.

Comment: И вообще здесь время - это понятие относительное, поэтому оно нафиг не нужно).

Comment: Уважаемые участники, хочется вспомнить (для справок) правило по теме. Усиление отрицания возможно следующими способами: а) Частицы ДАЛЕКО НЕ, ОТНЮДЬ НЕ; отрицательные местоимения и наречия НИКАК НЕ, НИСКОЛЬКО НЕ  и др. Частицы "совсем не, отнюдь не" используются как при усилении, так и при отрицании.

Comment: @Буратино А вот хороший вопрос - какова синтаксическая роль слова больше. Я что-то сомневаюсь, что оно входит в сказуемое. А может даже это неоднозначный вопрос. Ну и впихнуть "была" там везде надо, чтобы не думать о нулевых глаголах

Comment: @Sharon С ‟вовсе”, например, возможны два варианта. Предложение: ‟Я вовсе не герой” – и предложение: ‟Он не показался мне отталкивающим, а затем и вовсе показался неплохим человеком”. Да, два варианта. С ‟больше не” только один.